# How to receive all of the elements of parent class?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have abstract class `Product`, that is extended by class `TV` and `PC`. Both PC and TV have attribute productId (shared via `Product` parent class). My inheritance strategy is:`TABLE_PER_CLASS`. My question is: how can I get all of the products, despite if its `PC` or `TV`? is there something like 'findAllById()' in ProductRepository?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create 3 repositories, Product, Pc and Tv , I m not sure this gonna work for you because I dont have an example (you will need some fix perhaps) but its the princips you have to follow.

1st create generic product repository :

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ProductBaseRepository<T extends Product> 
extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {

  public T findById(Long id);

}
```

All methods in this repository will be available in the ProductRepository, in the PcRepository and in the TvRepository.

```
@Transactional
public interface ProductRepository extends ProductBaseRepository<User> { /* ... */ }

@Transactional
public interface PcRepository extends ProductBaseRepository<Pc> { /* ... */ }

@Transactional
public interface TvRepository extends ProductBaseRepository<Tv> { /* ... */ }
```

and this should work for you with good implementation!